# How can I define the image size for the derivative thumbnail in forge model derivative API?

Tags: typescript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm using the Model Derivative API in the following link:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeurn-GET/

to download the 3d views thumbnails from the model derivatives. There are three standard sizes for the thumbnail images.

The question is how can I determine the size I want to download in my request?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a thumbnail of the main document, you can use the [thumbnail](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-thumbnail-GET) endpoint, where the desired image size can be specified via query parameters.

If you're interested in non-standard thumbnails, for example, thumbnails of individual Revit views:

1. Use the [GET /modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/) request first to see all derivatives available for this model
2. Find the URN of the thumbnail you're interested in (it could look similar to `urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJ.../output/Resource/3D View/{3D} 98112/{3D}1.png`)
3. Pass this URN (this time **not** encoded in base64) into the [GET /modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/manifest/:derivativeUrn](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeurn-GET/) request

Comment: This one returns only the thumbnail of the design file. What I need is the thumbnail of each 3d view within this file. Although I retrieve a binary response, it seems like it is corrupted.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood the question. Let me update the answer.

Comment: When querying something like `curl -X GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJ.../manifest/urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJ.../output/Resource/3D_View/_3D_%20960621/_3D_1.png -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Authorization: Bearer <token>'`, I got a correct thumbnail. If you're still having issues with yours, and don't mind sharing the model or your app credentials, please contact us via forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com and we'll investigate it further.

Comment: I use the sample revit model advanced mep file.

Comment: That file seems to be working fine as well: https://pasteboard.co/IqvBWL9.png. Any specific details about how you're requesting the derivatives?